# SafeServiceClient not initializing properly

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

In my next.js app I'm initializing the SafeServiceClient like so:

```typescript
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import EthersAdapter from '@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib'
import SafeServiceClient from '@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client'
import { InjectedConnector } from '@web3-react/injected-connector'
import {ethers} from 'ethers'
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";

const txServiceUrl = 'https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global/';
declare let window: any;

function Comp() {

  const injected = new InjectedConnector({
    supportedChainIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, 42],
  })

  /// Local states
  const [safeService, setSafeService] = useState<any>()
  const [safes, setSafes] = useState([])

  // Hooks
  const { account, activate, deactivate } = useWeb3React();
  
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
  const safeOwner = provider.getSigner(0)

  const adapter = new EthersAdapter({
      ethers,
      signer: safeOwner
    })

  /** 
   *  Initialise: SafeServiceClient
   *  Fetch: Safes
   *  @issue SafeServiceClient not initialised properly
   * */ 
   useEffect(() => {        
    const fetchData = async (ownerAddress:string) => {
      const ethAdapter = adapter as EthersAdapter
      const initSafeService = new SafeServiceClient({ txServiceUrl, ethAdapter })

      // successfully returns safeService object
      console.log(initSafeService) 
      
      // returns error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEip3770Address')
      const fetchedSafes:any = await initSafeService.getSafesByOwner(ownerAddress)
      setSafes(fetchedSafes.safes)
      setSafeService(initSafeService)
    }
    if(account){
      fetchData(account)
    }
  }, [account]);



  /// Connect Metamask
  async function connect() {
    try {
    await activate(injected)//.then(() => initSafeService())
    } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    }
  }

  /// Disconnect Metamask
  async function disconnect() {
    try {
    deactivate()
    } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => connect()}>
        connect
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => disconnect()}>
        disconnect
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default Comp;
```

The `console.log(initSafeService)` returns the SafeServiceClient object successfully.
However, the `initSafeService.getSafesByOwner(ownerAddress)` returns error:

[image]

If I rerun the useEffect (by disconnecting and reconnecting the `account`) the error doesn't show and safes are fetched properly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an synchronization problem...

**EDIT**: change await because useEffect can't receive async functions...

Maybe you need to wait for the `fetchData()` function to finish doing it's thing?

```js
  useEffect(() => {        
    const fetchData = async (ownerAddress:string) => {
      const ethAdapter = adapter as EthersAdapter
      const initSafeService = new SafeServiceClient({ txServiceUrl, ethAdapter })
      console.log(initSafeService)
      const fetchedSafes = await initSafeService.getSafesByOwner(ownerAddress)
      setSafes(fetchedSafes.safes)
    }
    if(account){
      setSafeOwner(account as string);
      fetchData(account).then(() => {
        // do other dependent things...
      });
    }
  }, [account]);
```

Just an idea, since the `fetchData()` function is async...

Comment: It's not possible to await within useEffect hook, you'll have to create another async function within the hook for that, and then it'll just be an endless loop of functions awaiting each other I guess.

Comment: sorry, you're right... is setSafeOwner() async too? Is it required to be executed before the fetchData() async function?

Comment: setSafeOwner is just a react.useState hook. The error persists if I remove it.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could share more code...

Comment: I added a working example

Comment: I tried your code here and it's working... no error